# How to extend the “Content Porter 2009 SP2”?

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

I would like to extend/customize the content porter below are my thoughts:
•   I have list of items which needs to be ported (WebDAV path).
•   I want to select the items which needs to be ported from my list (could be xml or any other format) instead of selecting the items manually from different places.

Any idea/suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It is not officially supported, but you can manually generate ContentPorter config file. To see how to do it you can select items you like in CP GUI and then on the last step save configuration to file. You can then inspect this file and generate similar through code. Finally you can run content porter with this config file to get your items selected, or even run Content Porter in unattended mode.

You can also do all of this way simpler with Content Porter 2013